# Nagios3 with check_radius.pl and check_redis.pl (conflict?)

Tags: nagios, redis

Using Nagios3 on Ubuntu 15.04 to monitor a dozen or so CentOS, RHEL and Ubuntu hosts. Everything works just great, including the check_radius.pl plugin (3 hosts). After installing the Redis plugin (check_redis.pl) and configuring it to monitor several hosts, the check_radius.pl plugin begins to fail with a return message of: ** ePN /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_radius.pl Unknown option: host

When I disable the redis checks, check_radius.pl checks return to normal. They're not the same hosts. Suspecting a concurrency issue, I tried setting max_concurrent_checks to 1, 2 and 4. No effect. Check_radius.pl is the only Perl script (other than check_redis.pl) in this Nagios instance. No other Nagios checks are affected. I'm not strong on Perl, so any thoughts from Perl pros would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo in your nagios config, where an errant cut/paste switched radius and redis?  If you wanted to test this directly, you could try supplying the options meant for check_redis to a command-line test of check_radius and check the error received.

I recommend looking at your nagios config files closely to make sure you didn't use radius in place of redis (or vice-versa).

Comment: This is solid advice. The wild speculation in the original question is incorrect.

Comment: I have double- and triple-checked the configuration. Here are the definitions from the commands.cfg file:
# 'check_redis' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_redis
        command_line    $USER1$/check_redis.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $ARG1$ -T $ARG2$ -R -a $ARG3$ -w $ARG4$ -c $ARG5$
}

# 'check_radius' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_radius
        command_line    $USER1$/check_freeradius.pl -F status -host $HOSTADDRESS$ -port $ARG1$ -TIMEOUT $ARG2$ -SECRET $ARG3$ -CLIENT /usr/bin/radclient -W $ARG4$ -C $ARG5$
        }

Comment: have you tried switching the order of these lines in the config file to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes - I have tried switching them. No effect.

Comment: What about the service definitions?  Can you post them as well?

Comment: surround your text with backquotes `like this`

Comment: Does the nagios logfile have any clues?  Try a full stop/start of nagios rather than a reload.

Comment: I've done full restarts - no effect.
Log:
    [1430347077] SERVICE ALERT: sideshow;Radius status;UNKNOWN;SOFT;2;**ePN /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_freeradius.pl: "Unknown option: host".

Comment: Running the command from the bash prompt returns the correct [OK] result. But, when it runs within Nagios, I get the odd output (**ePN ...). What's really weird is that it works perfectly as long as I don't enable Redis monitoring on any hosts. The Redis monitoring always works.

Comment: Redis and Radius are the only two checks implemented with Perl, and I'm not strong on Perl.

Comment: define service{  
        use    prod-service  
        host_name   patty  
        service_description  Redis  
        check_command   check_redis!6379!"1,2"!blocked_clients,connected_clients!50,~!100,~   
        }  
  
define service{  
        use                             prod-service  
        host_name                       patty  
        service_description             Radius status  
        check_command                   check_radius!1812!1!testing123!5!10  
        }

Comment: I wonder if the perl modules are working with temp files or temp directories and those are conflicting with each other.  If both of these checks use the same base Nagios plugin library, you may want to look at the library code to see if/where it uses temp files.

Comment: Great suggestions. But, they don't use any of the same Perl modules and I don't see that either write to a tmp file or dir anywhere. At this point, I'm totally baffled. I have hundreds of checks on this Nagios config and have never seen anything like this.

Comment: When run from the command line, they each work perfectly. When only Radius checks (not Redis) checks are activated, they work fine. When the Redis checks are activated, they work fine but the Radius checks begin to fail. Somehow, these two Perl scripts are interacting, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: They may still conflict, actually.  Both scripts have this line `use lib '/usr/lib/nagios/plugins';` you may want to check to see if there is a basic nagios perl library there that they are sharing.

Comment: you can also change the debug level for nagios (check the nagios.cfg file).  It has debug values for many different things, and it may be helpful to turn it all the way up for a period of time to gather more information

Comment: I jacked up the debug level and there's nothing obvious. When I restarted, the Radius checks were OK and I got a RECOVERY state. Then on the next check (after the Redis checks had run once?), they went back to UNKNOWN state with the goofy...
    *ePN /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_freeradius.pl: "Unknown option: host".

Comment: Appreciate your help. Bailing out for the evening.

Comment: I'll let you know if I come up with anything else.

Comment: Comments are temporary and not intended for extended discussions. They can be removed at any time, and are not even visible to all users. Clarifications should be made by editing the original question, where they are visible to everyone.